# Как получить количество не используя GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

Я бэк енд разработчик и мои знания базы данных скудны (на уровне сделать запросы для даппера).

---

Бэк енд. Генерируется строки для (SELECT) и  (WHERE) передается в хранимую процедуру в базе данных (я не могу менять код так как много что завязано на нем)

---

База данных. получает данные и делает запрос
пример идет такой  (@FromString генерируется в хранимой процедуре)

```sql
SELECT ' + @SelectString + 
' FROM ' + @FromString + '
 WHERE ' + @WhereString + '
```

в итоговом варианте такой код (сокращенная часть)

```sql
SELECT cei_mot_count.cnt FROM someTable AS st
     LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.Id= st.ID
```

мне нужно как то получить количество данных есть не используя GROUP BY

---

Как я пытался решить проблему.

выводит количество 1

```sql
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
                        FROM  CEI_Motivations as mot 
                 WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL AND mot.Id= st.ID                    
                        GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count
```

думал что можно обратиться к джойну как к таблице

```sql
CROSS  APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
                    FROM  cei_mot as mot 
             WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL                    
                    GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT mot.*, COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt FROM CEI_Motivations as mot GROUP BY mot.Id) AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.StayingID = cs.ID
```

---

полный скрипт

```sql
USE [kuisdb_r3]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CreateAnalyticCEIReportDataSource]    Script Date: 9/26/2019 12:07:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateAnalyticCEIReportDataSource]
    @StatementDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01',
    @SelectStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @WhereStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @OrderStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @GroupStatement NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @OrganizationID INT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PreSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @FromStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @FromStatement = @FromStatement + N'
ConvictsStaying cs
INNER JOIN MainStaying ms ON cs.MainStayingID = ms.ID
left join CEI_PrivateCaseNumbers pcn on pcn.StayingID=cs.ID

                       left join CEI_PrivateCases pc on pcn.PrivateCaseID = pc.ID

--INNER JOIN CEI_PrivateCases pc ON pc.MainStayingID = ms.ID
--left JOIN CEI_PrivateCaseNumbers pcn ON pcn.StayingID = cs.ID and pcn.PrivateCaseID=pc.ID
INNER JOIN ConvictedPersons cp ON ms.ConvictedPersonID = cp.ID
INNER JOIN Person pers ON cp.PersonID = pers.ID

LEFT JOIN nsi.hCEI_PrivateCaseKinds pck ON pc.PrivateCaseKindID = pck.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_PrivateCaseReasons pcr ON pc.PrivateCaseReasonID = pcr.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_PrivateCaseEndReasons pcer ON pc.CaseEndReasonID = pcer.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_PrivateCaseEndReasons pcer1 ON pcn.CaseEndReasonID = pcer1.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_Accounting acc ON acc.StayingID = cs.ID
AND acc.ID in (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_Accounting
    WHERE StayingID = cs.ID
    ORDER BY AccountDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN CEI_AccountingLocalities accl ON accl.AccountingID = acc.ID
AND accl.ID in (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_AccountingLocalities
    WHERE AccountingID = acc.ID
    ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_PrivateCaseEndReasons pceracc on acc.RemoveReasonID = pceracc.ID

LEFT JOIN NSI.hBioSex sex ON pers.SexID = sex.ID

LEFT JOIN SUR.Organizations org ON cs.OrganizationID = org.ID
AND org.ID not in (7903, 7904)
INNER JOIN States st ON org.StateID = st.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_TransferRequests tr ON tr.StayingID = cs.ID
AND tr.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_TransferRequests
    WHERE StayingID = cs.ID
    ORDER BY RegDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN CEI_TransferRequestDetails trd ON trd.TransferRequestID = tr.ID AND trd.RequestStatusID = 4
AND trd.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_TransferRequestDetails
    WHERE TransferRequestID = tr.ID
    ORDER BY StatusRegDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_TransferRequestStatuses trs ON trd.RequestStatusID = trs.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_TransferRequests trfrom ON trfrom.StayingID = cs.ID AND trd.RequestStatusID = 5
AND trfrom.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_TransferRequests
    WHERE StayingID = cs.ID
    AND trd.RequestStatusID = 5
    ORDER BY RegDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN SUR.Organizations orgfrom ON orgfrom.ID = trfrom.ReceiverOrganizationID

LEFT JOIN CEI_TransferRequests trto ON trto.StayingID = cs.ID AND trd.RequestStatusID = 4
AND trto.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CEI_TransferRequests
    WHERE StayingID = cs.ID
    AND trd.RequestStatusID = 4
    ORDER BY RegDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN SUR.Organizations orgto ON orgto.ID = trto.SenderOrganizationID

LEFT JOIN NSI.hNationalities nat ON pers.NationalityID = nat.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCitizenships hcit ON pers.CitizenshipID = hcit.ID
LEFT JOIN PersonBirthPlaces pbp ON pbp.PersonID = pers.ID
AND pbp.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PersonBirthPlaces
    WHERE PersonID = pers.ID
)
LEFT JOIN Ates ate1 ON pbp.AteID = ate1.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCountries countr1 ON pbp.CountryID = countr1.ID

LEFT JOIN PersonDetails pd ON pd.ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID
LEFT JOIN PersonAddresses pa ON pd.ResidenceAddressID = pa.ID
LEFT JOIN PersonEducations pe ON pe.PersonID = pers.ID AND pe.IsInPrison = 0
AND pe.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PersonEducations
    WHERE PersonID = pers.ID
    AND IsInPrison = 0
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hEducationTypes edtype ON pe.EducationTypeID = edtype.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCountries countr2 ON pa.CountryID = countr2.ID
LEFT JOIN Ates ate2 ON pa.AteID = ate2.ID
LEFT JOIN Addresses addr ON pa.AddressID = addr.ID
LEFT JOIN Ates ate3 ON addr.AteID = ate3.ID

LEFT JOIN PersonDocuments persdoc ON pd.PersonDocumentID = persdoc.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hPersonDocumentTypes persdoct ON persdoc.DocumentTypeID = persdoct.ID

LEFT JOIN PersonMaterialStatuses pms ON  pd.PersonMaterialStatusID = pms.ID
--LEFT JOIN PersonMaterialStatuses pms ON pers.ID = pms.PersonID
--AND pms.ID in (
--  SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PersonMaterialStatuses 
--  WHERE PersonID = pers.ID
--)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hMaterialStatusTypes mst ON pms.MaterialStatusTypeID = mst.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_ConvictsHealthState chs ON chs.StayingID = cs.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_HealthStateTypes healtht ON chs.HealthStateTypeID = healtht.ID

LEFT JOIN PreviousConvictions pcss ON pcss.PrivateCaseID = pc.ID
AND pcss.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PreviousConvictions
    WHERE PrivateCaseID = pc.ID
    ORDER BY ConvictionDate DESC
)

LEFT JOIN NSI.hCareerTypes ct ON pd.CareerTypeID = ct.ID

LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_DisabilityGroups disg ON disg.ID = chs.DisabilityGroupID

LEFT JOIN ConvictedMainInfo cmi ON cmi.ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID
AND cmi.ID in (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ConvictedMainInfo
    WHERE ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID
)

--LEFT JOIN CEIMainView cmv ON cmv.ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID

LEFT JOIN Resolutions charger ON charger.MainStayingID = ms.ID AND charger.ResolutionTypeID = 2
LEFT JOIN Resolutions court4r ON pc.ResolutionID = court4r.ID
LEFT JOIN Resolutions court14r ON court14r.ID = ms.ID AND court14r.ResolutionTypeID = 14
LEFT JOIN CourtDecisions cd ON cd.ResolutionID = court4r.ID

LEFT JOIN InternalOrganizations courtio ON court4r.InternalOrganizationID = courtio.ID
LEFT JOIN SUR.Organizations courto ON courtio.OrganizationID = courto.ID

LEFT JOIN PunishmentMeasure pm ON pm.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID AND pm.IsMain = 1
LEFT JOIN ConvictedArticles ca ON ca.ResolutionID = cd.ResolutionID AND ca.IsMain = 1
LEFT JOIN NSI.UKArticles ua ON ca.ArticleID = ua.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hUKReleases ukrel ON ua.UKReleaseID = ukrel.ID

LEFT JOIN PunishmentMeasure pm2 ON pc.PunishmentMeasureID = pm2.ID  AND pm2.IsMain = 0    -- pm2.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID AND pm2.IsMain = 0
left join AdministrativeSupervision ass on cd.PetitionStatementID = ass.PetitionStatementID

LEFT JOIN nsi.hPunishmentKinds pk ON pm.PunishmentKindID = pk.ID

LEFT JOIN CourtDecisionDetails cdd ON cdd.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID

LEFT JOIN NSI.hHeaviness heav ON cdd.HeavinessID = heav.ID

LEFT JOIN Resolutions AS r1 ON r1.MainStayingID=cs.MainStayingID AND r1.ID in
 (SELECT TOP(1)hcsr.ResolutionID FROM 
  hsConvictsStayingResolutions  hcsr
  JOIN CourtDecisions AS cd ON cd.ResolutionID=hcsr.ResolutionID
  JOIN Resolutions AS r2 ON   r2.ID=hcsr.ResolutionID
  WHERE r2.MainStayingID=cs.MainStayingID AND hcsr.ConvictsStayingID=cs.ID AND r2.RegDate<=@StatementDate  AND cd.IsEffective=0  )

LEFT JOIN CourtDecisions parolecd ON parolecd.ResolutionID = court4r.ID 
AND parolecd.IsMasureChanged = 1
AND parolecd.ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM CourtDecisions 
    WHERE ResolutionID = court4r.ID 
    AND parolecd.IsMasureChanged = 1
    ORDER BY ID DESC
)
LEFT JOIN PunishmentMeasure pm0 ON pm0.ID=pc.PunishmentMeasureID
LEFT JOIN PunishmentMeasure parolepm on parolepm.ID in(select TOP 1 pm.ID 
from Resolutions r
 left join CourtDecisions cd On cd.ResolutionID = r.ID
 inner join PunishmentMeasure pm On pm.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID
where r.MainStayingID = cs.MainStayingID and r.Id in (select ResolutionID from hsConvictsStayingResolutions where ConvictsStayingID=cs.ID) and TermBeginDate is not null
order by ID desc)
--LEFT JOIN PunishmentMeasure parolepm ON parolepm.CourtDecisionID = parolecd.ID
--AND parolepm.ID IN (
--    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM PunishmentMeasure
--    WHERE CourtDecisionID = parolecd.ID
--    
 --   ORDER BY TermEndDate DESC
--)
LEFT JOIN ParoleTerms udopt ON 
udopt.ID IN (
    select TOP 1 pt.ID 
from  ParoleTerms pt 
join Resolutions r on r.ID=pt.ResolutionID
 left join CourtDecisions cd On cd.ResolutionID = r.ID
 inner join PunishmentMeasure pm On pm.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID 
where r.MainStayingID = cs.MainStayingID and  ParoleTypeID = 1 and r.Id in (select ResolutionID from hsConvictsStayingResolutions where ConvictsStayingID=cs.ID)  and TermBeginDate is not null  order by pt.ID desc
)
--LEFT JOIN ParoleTerms udopt ON udopt.ResolutionID = parolecd.ResolutionID
--AND udopt.ID IN (
--    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ParoleTerms
 --   WHERE ResolutionID = parolecd.ResolutionID
 --    AND ParoleTypeID = 1
  --  ORDER BY TermDate DESC
--)
LEFT JOIN ParoleTerms dopt ON 
 dopt.ID IN (
    select TOP 1 pt.ID 
from  ParoleTerms pt 
join Resolutions r on r.ID=pt.ResolutionID
 left join CourtDecisions cd On cd.ResolutionID = r.ID
 inner join PunishmentMeasure pm On pm.CourtDecisionID = cd.ID 
where  ParoleTypeID = 4 and r.MainStayingID = cs.MainStayingID and r.Id in (select ResolutionID from hsConvictsStayingResolutions where ConvictsStayingID=cs.ID)  and TermBeginDate is not null  order by pt.ID desc
)
-- JOIN ParoleTerms dopt ON dopt.ResolutionID = parolecd.ResolutionIDCEI_Motivations
--AND dopt.ID IN (
 --   SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM ParoleTerms
 --   WHERE ResolutionID = parolecd.ResolutionID
 --    AND ParoleTypeID = 4
 --   ORDER BY TermDate DESC
--)

LEFT JOIN NSI.hParoleTermTypes udoptt ON udopt.ParoleTermTypeID = udoptt.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hParoleTermTypes doptt ON dopt.ParoleTermTypeID = doptt.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations mot ON mot.StayingID = cs.ID
AND mot.ID in (
    select top 1 ID from CEI_Motivations 
    where StayingID = cs.ID
    ORDER BY DefectionDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_MotivationKinds motk ON mot.MotivationKindID = motk.ID
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_MotivationTypes mott ON mot.MotivationTypeID = mott.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations motiv ON motiv.StayingID = cs.ID
AND motiv.ID in (
    select top 1 ID from CEI_Motivations 
    where StayingID = cs.ID
    ORDER BY DefectionDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_DefectionTypes def ON motiv.DefectionTypeID = def.ID

LEFT JOIN CEI_Checks c ON c.ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID
AND c.ID in (
    select top 1 ID from CEI_Checks 
    where ConvictsStayingID = cs.ID
    ORDER BY CheckDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN NSI.hCEI_CheckKinds ck ON c.CheckKindID = ck.ID

LEFT JOIN Resolutions resPunish on resPunish.mainStayingID=ms.ID and resPunish.ID in (
select top(1) Resolutions.ID from CourtDecisions 
join Resolutions on Resolutions.ID=CourtDecisions.ResolutionID
join ConvictedArticles ca0 on ca0.ResolutionID=CourtDecisions.ResolutionID and ca0.ID in 
    (select top(1)ID from 
    ConvictedArticles where ResolutionID=CourtDecisions.ResolutionID)
join CourtDecisionDetails on CourtDecisionDetails.CourtDecisionID = CourtDecisions.ID
where Resolutions.MainStayingID=ms.ID and CourtDecisions.IsEffective = 1 and CourtDecisions.ResolutionID in (select ResolutionID from hsConvictsStayingResolutions where ConvictsStayingID=cs.ID) and CourtDecisionDetails.SentenceKindID in (1,7) and ca0.ID is not null
Order by Resolutions.RegDate DESC
)
LEFT JOIN CourtDecisions courtdPunish on courtdPunish.ResolutionID=resPunish.ID

--Дата вынесения предупреждений
LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.StayingID = cs.ID AND cei_mot.MotivationTypeID = 3 and cei_mot.MotivationDate <= @StatementDate
-----------------------
--Количество предупреждений вот тут я застрял !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
--LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.StayingID = cs.ID AND cei_mot_count.MotivationTypeID = 3 and cei_mot_count.MotivationDate <= @StatementDate
--LEFT JOIN ( SELECT mot.*, COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt FROM CEI_Motivations as mot GROUP BY mot.Id) AS cei_mot ON cei_mot.StayingID = cs.ID AND cei_mot.MotivationTypeID = 3 and cei_mot.MotivationDate <= @StatementDate

--OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
--                    FROM  CEI_Motivations as mot 
--             WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL AND mot.Id= st.ID                    
--                    GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count

--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, StayingID, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM CEI_Motivations GROUP BY Id,StayingID) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.StayingID = cei_mot.StayingID
--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Id, COUNT(cei_mot.Id) as cnt FROM cei_mot GROUP BY Id) as cei_mot_count ON cei_mot_count.Id IS NOT NULL
CROSS  APPLY (SELECT COUNT(mot.Id) as cnt     
                    FROM  cei_mot as mot 
             WHERE mot.Id IS NOT NULL                    
                    GROUP BY mot.Id) as cei_mot_count

--LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT post_id, count(*) cnt FROM post_comments GROUP BY post_id) x ON post.id = x.post_id

'
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalPrograms slp ON slp.StayingID = cs.ID
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalCare slc ON slc.SociallyLegalProgramID = slp.ID
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalCareDenial slcd ON slcd.SociallyLegalCareID = slc.ID
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalCareReceives slcrec ON slcrec.SociallyLegalCareID = slc.ID
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalCareReferrals slcref ON slcref.SociallyLegalCareID = slc.ID
--LEFT JOIN CEI_SociallyLegalCareProvidedAssistance slcpa ON slcpa.SociallyLegalCareReferralID = slcref.ID


    SET @Sql = @Sql + 
        N'DECLARE @StatementDate DATETIME = ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @StatementDate, 20) + '''; WITH CTE
  AS
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT
    ChildOrganizationID  
   FROM SUR.OrganizationRelations        
   WHERE ParentOrganizationID = ' + CAST(@OrganizationID AS nvarchar) + N' 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT        
    s.ChildOrganizationID
   FROM CTE C
    JOIN SUR.OrganizationRelations s
     ON C.ChildOrganizationID = s.ParentOrganizationID
  ) SELECT DISTINCT ' + @SelectStatement + 
        ' FROM ' + @FromStatement + 
        CASE WHEN @WhereStatement != '' THEN  ' WHERE ' + --+ N'(cs.MovementFromDate > ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @StatementDate, 20) + N''' OR cs.MovementFromDate IS NULL) 
        --AND (pc.CaseEndDate > ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @StatementDate, 20) + N''' OR pc.CaseEndDate IS NULL OR cs.StayingStateID = 2)
        'cs.IsCEI = 1 and cs.IsDeleted = 0
AND cs.OrganizationID IN (
    SELECT ChildOrganizationID FROM CTE
    UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(@OrganizationID AS nvarchar) + N'
) AND ' + @WhereStatement ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @GroupStatement != '' THEN ' GROUP BY ' + @GroupStatement ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN @OrderStatement != '' THEN ' ORDER BY ' + @OrderStatement ELSE '' END

         Insert Into dbo.AnaliticalTempQuery (SqlText) values(@Sql)

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: Да просто добавьте в список полей вывода `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY left_table.id IS NOT NULL)` - и тогда в КАЖДОЙ записи будет присутствовать поле с количеством записей в выборке, берите из любой. Или, если набор пуст, то количество, есссно, ноль.

Comment: `@SelectString = @SelectString + ', COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY left_table.id IS NOT NULL) AS TotalCount'`. Проверьте...

Comment: Альтернативный вариант - упихать всё в подзапрос, включая и ненавистный GROUP BY.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: Это Вы к чему? в предложенном к добавлению фрагменте нет ни AND, ни ORDER...

Comment: все дело в генерации строк со стороны бэк енда

Comment: Простите, я не могу понять этой фразы. Давайте так - нафиг "упрощения", покажите на стоящее содержимое каждой из трёх переменных (или итоговый текст запроса), а я покажу, как, в какую форму, его модифицировать.

Comment: залил полную версию

Comment: После применения "боевой раскраски" видно, что проблемная часть кода является куском в переменной `@FromStatement`. Но она длинная, и затруднительно понять, что и в каком разрезе нужно посчитать. Тем более что в проблемной точке Вы джойните ещё одну копию таблицы `CEI_Motivations`, причём по тем же условиям. Это явно лишнее. Вам не нужна вторая копия таблицы, надо, как я и написал выше, дополнить `@SelectStatement` так, как я показал выше. Ну и поскольку нужно посчитать количество записей по cei_mot, то её ID (или поле, по которому она связывается) и используется в выражении для PARTITION BY.

Comment: можете подсказать что делать в этой ситуации ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас финальный запрос, который отдаётся EXEC-у, выглядит как-то так:

```
WITH 
CTE AS ( ... ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ' + @SelectStatement + 
' FROM '  + @FromStatement + ...
```

В середине  присутствует фрагмент со ссылкой на таблицу, из которой нужно получить требуемые данные:

```
LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot 
    ON cei_mot.StayingID = cs.ID 
   AND cei_mot.MotivationTypeID = 3 
   and cei_mot.MotivationDate <= @StatementDate
-- Количество предупреждений вот тут я застрял !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
-- LEFT JOIN CEI_Motivations AS cei_mot_count 
--     ON cei_mot_count.StayingID = cs.ID 
--    AND cei_mot_count.MotivationTypeID = 3 
--    and cei_mot_count.MotivationDate <= @StatementDate
```

т.е. нужно получить количество соотв. записей в таблице `CEI_Motivations`.

Чтобы получить общее количество, достаточно модифицировать, например, так:

```
WITH 
CTE AS ( ... ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ' + @SelectStatement + 
+ ', COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cei_mot.StayingID IS NOT NULL) AS TotalCount ' + 
' FROM '  + @FromStatement + ...
```

Тогда в каждой записи будет общее количество not-null записей из указанной таблицы по всей выборке.

Если же требуется считать отдельно для каждой группы, которая присутствует в итоговой выборке, и которая определяется выражением в переменной `@GroupStatement`, то это выражение необходимо добавить в выражение фрейма, получив нечто типа

```
WITH 
CTE AS ( ... ) 
SELECT DISTINCT ' + @SelectStatement + 
+ ', COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ' + @GroupStatement + ', cei_mot.StayingID IS NOT NULL) AS Motivations_Count ' + 
' FROM '  + @FromStatement + ...
```

PS. Хотя мне непонятна суть происходящего. Особенно наличие одновременно и GROUP BY, и SELECT DISTINCT - какое-то масло масляное...

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cei_mot, cei_mot.id IS NOT NULL) не помогает

Comment: @GroupStatement + ' какие данные туда нужно вводить?

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cei_mot.StayingID IS NOT NULL) выдает ошибку Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: @RamazanovAdilbek Источник появления ошибки мне непонятен - на модельном fiddle операция выполняется без проблем и корректно. Вероятно, тут надо разбираться уже с конкретным запросом, в именно том виде, в каком он передаётся оператору `EXEC sp_executesql @Sql`...